# How to ask the confirm alert while delete or uninstall the midlet application on mobile?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, midlet, wap

I need to ask the confirm alert while user delete the my Java ME application on mobile. Is it possible? I want to ask like **Sure to delete this application?** This question is YES/NO type. If user press yes, automatically open the our survey page on wap browser. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question this is possible in part.

There are two attributes you can add to the jad to trigger on deletion.

**MIDlet-Delete-Notify** (since MIDP 2.0)   This property indicates the location (URL) for posting removal status. You can use URL rewriting to encode tracking information for the MIDlet suite. The URL can't be longer than 256 UTF-8-encoded characters.

**MIDlet-Delete-Confirm**   The user will see this confirmation prompt when removing a MIDlet suite.

So the one can notify you and the other can show a message.  Perhaps in the message you can put a short unique goo.gl URL to the survey and hope the user visits it from memory, or use a single short URL easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook for that in J2ME. It is part of the host operating system. So to make it short. You cannot achieve this.

Comment: There are some hooks, have a look at my answer.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that. Sounds nice. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: No problem, just reminds of the saying that goes like "if someone says it's not possible, don't believe.  Keep asking till someone says, yes I've done it."